# Pass parameter from Controller to Doctrine EventListener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am reading this tutorial to setup a Doctrine EventListener to upload and edit file in entity : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/603/how-to-configure-a-file-uploader-for-a-single-field-doctrine-entity-in-symfony-3-3

I want to pass dynamic parameters from the controller to the service. I modified the FileUploader to give path and filename from the controller. But I can't get these parameters from DoctrineEventListener.

My FileUploader :

```
    /**
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 * @param string $name
 * @return string $fileName
 */
public function getUniqueName(UploadedFile $file, $name) {
    $fileName = $name.'_'.md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

    return $fileName;
}
/**
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 * @param string $targetDir
 * @param string $name
 * @return string
 */
public function uploadImage(UploadedFile $file, $targetDir, $name)
{
    $fileName = $this->getUniqueName($file, $name);

    if ($file->guessExtension() == 'gif' || $file->guessExtension() == 'jpeg' ||
        $file->guessExtension() == 'pjpeg' || $file->guessExtension() == 'png')
    {
        $file->move($targetDir, $fileName);
        return $fileName;
    }
    else {
        return 'Type de photo non supporté. Veuillez choisir un fichier .png ou .jpg.';
    }

}
```

The rest of my code is the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: The example which you are following is based on the idea that the controller doesn't participate at all in this file uploading, i.e. I'm not quite sure why you're using this example as your base if you need to pass some parameters from the controller? You could take a look at the basic symfony file uploading example https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/upload_file.html, use custom annotations if that would be applicable for you, or just store the required additional data into your entity and fetch it from there (which sort of doesn't fit that well this concept of using the listener though)..

Comment: Actually, I got the upload process working without the example with the Controller and a Service. But I have some trouble setting up the edit process. I tried with the documentation you linked but it didn't work so I tried something else but after reading you, I don't think it will work either

Comment: In your case, ejuhjav's 2nd option might be the cleanest - save additional data to your entity before persisting and then it will be available in your listener.

Comment: what exactly is the issue that you're running into with the edit process? The example in the link looks to be covering the edit cases as well (both when no new file is provided and when new file is provided)?

Comment: Problem is when I go to the edit form, the file saved into the entity is not shown and if I submit it, I have a validation error saying it can't be empty. The link I used, as you said, is not fitting my case. I tried with the documentation but even when I create the File object and set it into my entity, I have the same error